# How to Create C DLL using Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c, visual-studio, dll

I've been doing all of my development using C# in Visual Studio, first 2010 and now 2012.  I need to create a DLL using C language for the project I'm working on.  Only when I do File | New Project, I can't find an option for creating a DLL using C.

How do you do this?

Comment: Good question. While creating DLL, we need to maintain several rules and regulations. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ez7dh12.aspx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's under File / New / Project / Templates / Visual C++ / Win32 / Win32 Project.  Follow the wizard, and you'll be offered "DLL" on the second page.

(This is with Visual Studio 2012 - some of the wording may differ in other versions.)

Comment: @RichieHindle The path (especially the Visual ++ part) suggests that this is true for creating a C++ DLL.  Would you follow the same instruction if you specifically wanted a C DLL?

Comment: @Joe: Those instructions will get you a C++ DLL in the sense that some C++ files will be created for you, but there's nothing stopping you from adding C files to the project, and/or removing the original C++ files.

Answer (score -1):

here's the full tuto to do so : [Walkthrough: Creating and Using a Dynamic Link Library (C++)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636.aspx)